# Words are margined from navigation bar & how to extend navigation bar

Tags: html, css, web

so I am making a website for a friend of mine, and I had to position the image and navigation bar "relative" so I can position them properly.
But now when I add paragraph tags, theres a huge margin with the words and navigation bar

Also, how do i extend my navaigation bar so it goes across the page?

Code: http://jsbin.com/puzihahaxu/edit?html,output

(you can see the problem in jsbin)

Thank you for the help!
- Anthony DeMatteis

Comment: `#page1 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 1800px;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 265px;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
}` I can't even

Comment: Ok the problem is caused by having unnecessary padding and defining heights and widths.. you don't really need to define height or width for elements that are supposed to render based on their content.. because of so much padding you were forced to use position relative to fix most of the stuff which caused a lot of whitespace..

Answer (score 1):

The code has a lot of clutter, as mentioned in my comment: excessive padding caused weird positioning, please keep in mind that you have to consider various screen resolutions when you design a website, otherwise it would look nice on your screen and strange on other computers and you will wonder why... so I would advise going back a few steps and understanding the default and basic styling of each element and how the HTML box model works. Have a look at my simplified example and I hope you learn from it:

https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/oo8sk8uw/

```css
/* main */

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: darkseagreen;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#page {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background: #FFF;
}


/* header */

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

h1 {
  color: firebrick;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

/* menu */

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:15px;
  font-size: 15pt;
  margin:0;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li a:link {
  color: green;
}

ul li a:visited {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

ul li a:active {
  background-color: grey;
}

#word {
  margin-top:20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <img src="header.jpg" alt="Real Estate Lawyer" id="header">
  <h1> John De Matteis </h1>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="john.html"> Home </a> </li>
      <li><a href="home.html"> About </a> </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact Us </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="word">
    <p> This is some sample text egin by considering two key questions that ultimately summarize the return on your efforts: How much impact will addressing that issue have? Consider your essential question and your targeted objective. How far will addressing
      this issue get you towards your goal? How easy will it be to design and implement a solution? Consider the complexity of the issue, the amount of time and resources required, and risks to success. Ask these questions for each issue, tagging the
      issue with a designation of High-, Medium-, or Low-Impact, and High-, Medium-, or Low-Ease. To show how the different issues compare we will plot them on a 2x2 matrix, like the one shown below. One axis will correspond to Ease of Execution; the
      other axis will correspond to Potential Impact. Plot out your solutions on the matrix, and focus on those faegin by considering two key questions that ultimately summarize the return on your efforts: How much impact will addressing that issue have?
      Consider your essential question and your targeted objective. How far will addressing this issue get you towards your goal? How easy will it be to design and implement a solution? Consider the complexity of the issue, the amount of time and resources
      required, and risks to success. Ask these questions for each issue, tagging the issue with a designation of High-, Medium-, or Low-Impact, and High-, Medium-, or Low-Ease. To show how the different issues compare we will plot them on a 2x2 matrix,
      like the one shown below. One axis will correspond to Ease of Execution; the other axis will correspond to Potential Impact. Plot out your solutions on the matrix, and focus on those faegin by considering two key questions that ultimately summarize
      the return on your efforts: How much impact will addressing that issue have? Consider your essential question and your targeted objective. How far will addressing this issue get you towards your goal? How easy will it be to design and implement
      a solution? Consider the complexity of the issue, the amount of time and resources required, and risks to success. Ask these questions for each issue, tagging the issue with a designation of High-, Medium-, or Low-Impact, and High-, Medium-, or
      Low-Ease. To show how the different issues compare we will plot them on a 2x2 matrix, like the one shown below. One axis will correspond to Ease of Execution; the other axis will correspond to Potential Impact. Plot out your solutions on the matrix,
      and focus on those fa </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the help !! For future references, how can i properly position elements without the unnecessary padding and margins?

Comment: through trail and error and lots of code inspection. This might be helpful: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp but I rarely see any element with padding of more than 100px, when you start resorting to such high numbers for padding, margin or positioning then it means something might be wrong, just try adding one element at a time and see how it renderns, and never set heigh for a container because when you set height then it will be fixed, ideally we want the height to change depending on how much text there is, right? good luck! P.S you can use percentages to measure instead of px

Answer (score 0):

May be it will work
**HYML Code:**

```
<div id="page">
  <img src="header.jpg" alt="Real Estate Lawyer" id="header">
  <h1> John De Matteis </h1>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="john.html"> Home </a> </li>
      <li><a href="home.html"> About </a> </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact Us </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="word">
    <p> This is some sample text egin by considering two key questions that ultimately summarize the return on your efforts: How much impact will addressing that issue have? Consider your essential question and your targeted objective. How far will addressing
      this issue get you towards your goal? How easy will it be to design and implement a solution? Consider the complexity of the issue, the amount of time and resources required, and risks to success. Ask these questions for each issue, tagging the
      issue with a designation of High-, Medium-, or Low-Impact, and High-, Medium-, or Low-Ease. To show how the different issues compare we will plot them on a 2x2 matrix, like the one shown below. One axis will correspond to Ease of Execution; the
      other axis will correspond to Potential Impact. Plot out your solutions on the matrix, and focus on those faegin by considering two key questions that ultimately summarize the return on your efforts: How much impact will addressing that issue have?
      Consider your essential question and your targeted objective. How far will addressing this issue get you towards your goal? How easy will it be to design and implement a solution? Consider the complexity of the issue, the amount of time and resources
      required, and risks to success. Ask these questions for each issue, tagging the issue with a designation of High-, Medium-, or Low-Impact, and High-, Medium-, or Low-Ease. To show how the different issues compare we will plot them on a 2x2 matrix,
      like the one shown below. One axis will correspond to Ease of Execution; the other axis will correspond to Potential Impact. Plot out your solutions on the matrix, and focus on those faegin by considering two key questions that ultimately summarize
      the return on your efforts: How much impact will addressing that issue have? Consider your essential question and your targeted objective. How far will addressing this issue get you towards your goal? How easy will it be to design and implement
      a solution? Consider the complexity of the issue, the amount of time and resources required, and risks to success. Ask these questions for each issue, tagging the issue with a designation of High-, Medium-, or Low-Impact, and High-, Medium-, or
      Low-Ease. To show how the different issues compare we will plot them on a 2x2 matrix, like the one shown below. One axis will correspond to Ease of Execution; the other axis will correspond to Potential Impact. Plot out your solutions on the matrix,
      and focus on those fa </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
/* main css*/

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;}
html,body {
  background: darkseagreen;
  font-family: monospace;
}
#page {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background: #FFF;
}


/* header css*/

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
h1 {
  color: firebrick;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

/* menu css*/
ul li, ul li a{text-decoration:none;} 

#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:15px;
  font-size: 15pt;
  margin:0;
}
ul li a {
  width: 100%;
}
ul li a:link {
  color: green;
}
ul li a:visited {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
ul li a:active {
  background-color: grey;
}
#word {
  margin-top:20px;
  position: relative;
}
```